# Pandas – lowest value in last x columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe in Python. I like to find minimum value in the last 10 columns in each lines.

I tried this:

> df['min_value'] = df.min(axis=1)
>
> 1, 3, 56, 7, ,23 ,46, 234, 23, 45, 123, 23, 64, 27, 12, 78  ==> 1
>
> 4, 5, 6, 73, ,82 ,66, 24, 243, 345, 12, 22, 46, 7, 21, 88  ==> 4

but I like to check only the last 10 elements.

> 1, 3, 56, 7, ,23 ,**46, 234, 23, 45, 123, 23, 64, 27, 12, 78**  ==> 12
>
> 4, 5, 6, 73, ,82 ,**66, 24, 243, 345, 12, 22, 46, 7, 21, 88**  ==> 7

any idea?

Comment: `df['col'] = df.iloc[:, -10:].min(axis=1)`

Comment: `df.T.tail(10).min()`

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
df = df.assign(min_value=df.iloc[:, -10:].values.min(1)) # column name: min_value
```